# Using "new" and "if" statements together - syntax related

Tags: c++, if-statement, new-operator

**So sorry everyone. I meant for there to be an asterisk in the code I posted. Please answer again.**

I'm doing a code review for a coworker, and I saw the following statement pop up:

```
if ((someClass *object1 = new someClass))
{
    // Do work
}
```

Does this statement say the same as the following?

```
someClass *object1 = new someClass;
if (object1)
{
    // Do work
}
```

I'm just trying to see if they are equal so we don't get any bugs.

Comment: I think, 'new' throws exception in case of failure(bad_alloc exception).

Comment: The redundant parentheses are to disable a warning from GCC (and Clang) about an assignment in a conditional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't create an object inside an `if` condition  in the first form unless the type appear immediately inside the parenthesis, so:

```
if (someClass* object1 = new Someclass(...)) { ... }
```

Or, in general:

```
if (someType object1 = whatever) { ... }

if (someType object1{...constructor args}) { ... }
```

That syntactic detail aside - the main differences are that the above form uses the `if` scope to control

- the `object1` **variable's lifetime** - the destructor will be invoked when the `if` terminates (which might be important if your variable's controlling a resource, but pointers don't have destructors anyway so you'd need to ensure you call `delete` before the `if` scope finishes - do consider using a smart pointer), and
- the `object1` identifier itself, which can be freely used in the enclosing scope for some other unrelated variable.

In your second form the variable remains in scope after the `if`'s scope, and the identifier can't be reused until the end of the scope it's in.

The default of behaviour of `new` is to throw an exception if it can't return a pointer to newly allocated memory, so the `if` statement would only be skipped in that case, making the code equivalent to:

```
...
{
    someClass* object1 = new SomeClass;
    // other if content is effectively in a scope here

    // to avoid a leak, must either:
    - delete object1;
    - copy/save the pointer somewhere to delete later 
}
...
```

Comment: The main difference really needs to be accented because that is a major league difference about the scope!

Comment: @RichardChambers In theory, yes, but in practice...  If the end of scope is an issue, you're probably doing too much in the function.  And embedding a definition in a flow control statement definitely comes under the heading of obfuscation.

Comment: @JamesKanze, I was merely asking Tony D to emphasize the scope issue, an emphasis that was not easily apparent in his original post.  He updated and expanded his original post which is much more useful now.

Comment: @RichardChambers I understand.  But IMHO, the readability issue is more important.

Comment: yeah I have trouble.

Comment: In fact you can **BUT ONLY IF** you provide a boolean operator.

Example:
`struct EventScope 
{
 EventScope(Event & event) : event(&event) { startEvent(event); }
 ~EventScope() { stopEvent(*event); }

 operator bool() const { return true; }

 Event * event;
};`
 
Then:
`#define watchEvent(event) if (EventScope __EventScope__ = EventScope(event))`
And you use this way:
`watchEvent(myEvent) { ... }`
That will compute the time spent into the scope amongst other infos.

Comment: Oh I forgot to say I don't see the point of using 'new' and 'delete' in such a construct. Making the class in the stack is for the scope time far better in both readibility and efficiency.

Comment: @Tony D, I was speaking about the versions without pointer and "new" and "delete", like 'if (someType object1 = whatever) { ... }' which I use sometimes for recording events in a scope or catching OpenGL errors with a nice call stack (through embedded scopes) to pinpoint the offensive callers. To use those forms, you need to define a bool operator in this "someType" class.

Comment: It seems you misunderstood my answer.  You say "in fact you can", presumably because my answer starts with "You can't..." and you know it's possible to do something like that asked in the question.  If you read my answer, you'll see I'm saying you can't have `if ((type variable...))` with double parenthesis - you must use one pair.  I have said "you can" otherwise to creating a variable for the duration of the `if` statement.  That you need `operator bool()` - or another conversion operator to a type that can be converted to `bool`, is true and a useful comment - not discussed in my answer.

Comment: "In fact you can *BUT ONLY IF*" was only regarding with pointer-less forms. Sorry for the glitch :).

Answer (score 2):

Strange code. Does it really work?

There is an error in the code. You should have written it like this:

```
someClass* object1 = new someClass;
```

In addition, I'd rather use std::unique_ptr to store the memory.

```
std::unique_ptr<someClass> object1(new someClass);
if (object1)
{
}
```

Comment: It is written like that, I made a mistake when posting the question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like neither one should compile. Assuming you meant `someClass* object1 = new someClass` then the only difference between the two is when the `object1` variable goes out of scope, and consequently when it needs to be cleaned up. When inside the `if` it goes out of scope with the `if`, while the second version goes out of scope in the enclosing scope.

But C++ is not Java, and given that it's being created in the very local scope of an `if` statement I would recommend to avoid `new` here entirely and just allocate it on the stack. Enclose in `{ }` if you need to control lifetime:

```
someClass object1;
// Do work
```

Finally note that by default `new` will never return 0/null but throws an exception. Thus the if check in the original version would have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

If the `new` fails, it will return a `bad_alloc_exception` that you should catch in your program. So in this particular case I don't see a purpose for the `if` to exist since it is right after the allocation.

One way for your `new` to not throw a `bad_alloc_exception` in case of failure is to specify the `nothrow`:

```
someClass* object1 = new(nothrow) someClass;
```

In case of failure `object1 = nullptr` and you can test

```
if (object1 != nullptr)
```

or

```
if ((someClass* object1 = new(nothrow) someClass))
```

Be careful with the second version since it will be out of scope after the closing of the `if` statement and so it need to be cleaned within this scope using `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you called  `set_new_handler()` to avoid the allocation error to throw a `bad_alloc` exception instead of returning null (default).

The shown syntaxes are still incorrect but the following compiles :

```
if (someClass *object1 = new someClass)
{
    // Do work
    delete object1; // if you do not, you will have a memory leak 
                    // because object1 goes out of scope on next line
}
// object1 is now out of scope 

someClass *object2 = new someClass;
if (object2)
{
    // Do work
}
// object2 is still in scope and can be used
delete object2;
```

So the difference is only that in first syntax the pointer goes out of scope at the end of the if block and **must** be freed before to avoid a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle difference between

```
if ((someClass *object1 = new someClass))
{
    // Do work

    delete object1;
}

object1 = 0; // ERROR!!!!!
```

And

```
someClass *object1 = new someClass;
if (object1)
{
    // Do work

    delete object1;
}

object1 = 0; // OK
```

In the first case, *object1* can only be accessed in the conditional expression **AND** in the scoped block of *if*. While in the second case, you can still access *object1* after *if*.